# What are some good resources books/websites for learning basic home wiring?

Tags: electrical, repair, maintenance

As part of Home maintenance, I need some electrification work. Looking for some basics of home electrification like `phase`, `neutral` things, `how to connect a fan regulator` ....

Comment: This question is too broad.  Try asking a more specific question, like "How do I rewire a switch/light/receptacle?" or "What are some good resources books/websites for learning basic home wiring?".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is what actually needed. i am bad at asking questions :)

Comment: If you are interested in learning the basichome wiring then you can visit the youtube channel of some popular electrical youtube channel.
They will show you details about it.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is too broad to answer in this forum. Electrical work is an exact science with no room for error.  Mistakes can cause personal injury, death, or the danger of fire. If you have no background or training I would seriously suggest you hire a pro.  If you really want to learn, there are some good books that teach the basics. These books can be found at any home improvement store. A better alternative would be to learn from a pro with some personal instruction and the comfort of knowing a pro has checked your work.
I cannot overstate the danger of improperly done electrical work. Be safe and be smart!

Comment: I am not doing electrical work. Just some minor works only. looking for some good books, articles explaining that. Hope you could help me

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's "minor" or not. Even something as "simple" as changing a regular light switch to a dimmer can cause injuries, death, or fire, if done incorrectly. It's not hard to learn, but you need to learn the basics.